# jQuery slidebar on delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 slidbars but when I move them to get the steps I should to double click. So if I have 3 steps and I click on step 3 it doesn't work. I have double-click to work. The following function I am using.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider.slider1').slider({
        min: 1,
        max: 2,
        tooltip: 'hide',
        value: 1
    });
    $('.slider.slider2').slider({
        min: 1,
        max: 4,
        tooltip: 'hide',
        value: 1
    });
    $('.slider.slider3').slider({
        min: 1,
        max: 3,
        tooltip: 'hide',
        value: 1
    });
    $('.btn.btn-back').click(function(event) {
        changePanel('test');
    });
    $('.slider.slider1, .slider.slider2, .slider.slider3').on('slideStop', function(event) {
        var id = $(this).closest('.lifestyle-form').attr('id');
        changePanel(getData(id), id);
    });
    $('.lifestyle-form .checkboxs input').on('change', function(event) {
        var id = $(this).closest('.lifestyle-form').attr('id');
        changePanel(getData(id), id);
    });

function getData(id) {
    $id = $('#'+id);
    var mumdad = $id.find('.slider1').data("value") ? $id.find('.slider1').data("value") : 1;
    var selectedChildren = $id.find('.slider2').data("value") ? $id.find('.slider2').data("value") : 1;
    var rsu = $id.find('.slider3').data("value") ? $id.find('.slider3').data("value") : 1;
    var selectedGender = "";
    var selectedLocation = "";
    var activityDefinesStandard = true;
    switch (mumdad) {
        case 1:
            selectedGender = 'mum';
            break;
        case 2:
            selectedGender = 'dad';
            break;
    }
    switch (rsu) {
        case 1:
            selectedLocation = 'rural';
            break;
        case 2:
            selectedLocation = 'suburban';
            break;
        case 3:
            selectedLocation = 'urban';
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Update your question with a minimum example of a slider that exhibits the behavior you're seeing. No need for three of them, unless the problem only manifests if you have three sliders on the page.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0b3uxj53/ have a look on this I activate the tool tip to see how it works

Comment: I still don't know what behavior you're trying to implement. The fiddle has no slider, just a couple of images. The tool tip moves if I click some arbitrary point and drag it, but I can't see what you're after.

Comment: If you click once in right side in that box is shown 2 but the tooltip say is 1 if you click again in right side the tool time will say that is 2 as well. so what I want is to have 2 on both from beginning

Comment: I didn't know you could use ternary operators with jQuery objects, so thanks for that.